# YoutubePlayer - onError method is not getting called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tv

I'm using YoutubePlayer to play YouTube videos. I want to show a network error dialog when the internet is not available. I'm using the AbstractYouTubePlayerListener callback to listen for network errors, but the **onError** method is not getting called when the network is not available.
I'm building this app for **Android-Tv**.

```
private fun initializePlayer() {
    val customPlayerUi =
        binding.youtubePlayerView.inflateCustomPlayerUi(R.layout.yt_custom_player_ui)
    binding.youtubePlayerView.getYouTubePlayerWhenReady(object : YouTubePlayerCallback {
        override fun onYouTubePlayer(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
            this@YoutubeVideoFragment.initializedYouTubePlayer = youTubePlayer
            val customPlayerUiController = YtCustomPlayerController(
                requireContext(),
                customPlayerUi,
                youTubePlayer
            )
            youTubePlayer.addListener(customPlayerUiController)
            if (isEulaAccepted) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(
                    glance.peek.videoPeek.video.youtubeVideo.videoId,
                    videoStartTime.toFloat()
                )
            }
            if (videoItemBinding.nudgeReaction.visibility == View.VISIBLE &&
                videoItemBinding.textPre.text == getString(R.string.skipping_to_next_video)
            ) {
                videoItemBinding.nudgeReaction.setGone()
            }
        }
    })

    binding.youtubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(object :
        AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
        override fun onStateChange(
            youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer,
            state: PlayerConstants.PlayerState
        ) {
            handleVideoStateChange(state)
        }

        override fun onCurrentSecond(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, second: Float) {
            if (seekRequestedTime == -1 || seekRequestedTime == second.toInt()) {
                // when user starts seeking,running time is getting updated parallely.So,to avoid jerk,will update running time after user seek time is reached
                // else if user is not seeking by default seekRequestedTime will be -1
                updateVideoRunningTime(second)
                seekRequestedTime = -1
            }
        }

        override fun onVideoDuration(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, duration: Float) {
            currentSeekBar.max = duration.toInt()
            updateUIDuration(duration)
        }

        override fun onError(
            youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer,
            error: PlayerConstants.PlayerError
        ) {
            super.onError(youTubePlayer, error)
            Timber.i("onError: $error")
            setErrorCodes("Youtube error:${error.name}")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like that the `onError` method handle this kind of errors.

[Here](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/pierfrancescosoffritti/androidyoutubeplayer/core/player/PlayerConstants.kt) are the error codes definded:

```
    enum class PlayerError {
        UNKNOWN, INVALID_PARAMETER_IN_REQUEST, HTML_5_PLAYER, VIDEO_NOT_FOUND, VIDEO_NOT_PLAYABLE_IN_EMBEDDED_PLAYER
    }
```

I would check the internet connection first and then call the video player.

Try to read the state of player. If it is buffering, then I would display that.

```
    enum class PlayerState {
        UNKNOWN, UNSTARTED, ENDED, PLAYING, PAUSED, BUFFERING, VIDEO_CUED
    }
```

Comment: But I want to show dialog when the video is playing and suddenly a network issue occurs.

Comment: You don't get this out of the box from the player. But when the `PlayerState` is `BUFFERING` you can check the network connection manually. If user is offline show a dialog.